# Can you set a machine to always load UEFI menu on startup?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, uefi

I recently dual booted my computer (Windows 10 & Ubuntu) and I can only ever seem to enter into the UEFI menu to choose my boot device from a restart of *Windows* but never Ubuntu.

Do machines have a setting to always show the UEFI menu on startup or restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, machines do not typically have an option to always show the UEFI menu (though some machines might). But, using Grub as a boot menu is a good alternative which is always available.

I too dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu:

```
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  ...
Boot0002* ubuntu    ...
```

As you can see, my Ubuntu partition is first in the boot order. I have Grub installed on this partition, and I have configured Grub to know about my Windows partition:

```
$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
...
menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 6092-9930
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
...
```

Whenever I reboot my PC, the UEFI firmware loads Grub and I use the Grub menu to choose Windows or Ubuntu.